# MySQL resultset to array for use in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to understand how this works, and so far, I found a workaround but it's not as nice as I had hoped.

Say I get some resultset from a query like so:

```
SELECT id FROM photos WHERE some clause
```

And I'd like put the resultset in a where clause like so:

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE photo_id IN ( array I just received )
```

How would I do this with a nested query? I tried looking up subqueries to no avail. Joins are not my strong suit but I fear I will need them in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE photo_id IN (SELECT id FROM photos WHERE some clause)
```

but this should also work:

```
SELECT tags.* FROM tags INNER JOIN photos ON (tags.photo_id=photos.id AND some clause)
```

Comment: Okay so I was right in both hunches.. thanks a bunch, will test now.